# Java FX - Controlling one combobox/choicebox using other combobox/choicebox

Tags: javafx

I want to change the combobox by selecting item from another combobox. Means, I want to control one combobox using other combobox. For example, if I have a combobox containing names and other containing countries, then if I select Mumbai from names then other combobox should automatically display India.

Please help me out a little bit to solve this problem. A piece of code will work for me to explain.

Comment: Please review the [ask] and [mcve] sections of the Help area and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean where the second combobox is dependent on what is chosen in the first

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ComboBox comboBox2 = new ComboBox();

        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3");
        comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            comboBox2.getItems().clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                comboBox2.getItems().add(comboBox.getValue().toString());
            }
        });


        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, comboBox2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```